Reasoning about convergent infinite series
As I understand it, if $p > 1$, then $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^p}$ converges.
Intuitively, it would then follow that for $s > t > 1$:
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^t} > \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^s}$$
Would it be correct then to suppose for that any real number $r > 0$, there exists a real value $x$ such that $x > 1$ and:
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n^x} = r$$

You can define the function $$\zeta\colon \mathbb R_{>1}\to \mathbb R, \; x\mapsto \sum_{n\geq 1}\frac1{n^x}.$$
This function is the Riemann-$\zeta$ function and is in particular continuous. You can now use the IVT to achieve your statement. (Consider: $\lim_{x\to 1^+}\zeta(x)=+\infty$ and $\lim_{x\to\infty}\zeta(x)=1$.)

Now that I have mistyped, you need $r> 1$, of course.  All summands are positive and the first one is already $1$.

Unfortunately, there's no consensus about whether to include $0$ in $\Bbb N$. To avoid that issue you could write $\displaystyle\sum_{n\ge 1}$ if you want to avoid $\displaystyle\sum_{n=1}^\infty$

@jjagmath yeah right, I have improved it.
